# jquery datatable - unexpected vertical scrollbar is shown if a row is empty

Tags: jquery, datatables

There are situations where my application receives an array of objects with records having empty value in all the properties. In this case, all the cells in the entire row will be empty.

During this scenario, the datatable shows vertical scrollbar.

In the below example, the scrolly is set to '30vh'. But, for just 2 records, the vertical scrollbar is displaying.

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```js
var data = [];
        for ( var i=0 ; i<2 ; i++ ) {
        
            var record = ['','','','','',''];
            if (i > 0)
            {
            record = [
            '', 
            'First Name ' + i, 
            'Last Name '+ i, 
            'Postal - ' + i, 
            'ZIP - '+ i, 
            'USA' ]
            }
            data.push( record );
        }
         
        var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
            data:           data,
            deferRender:    true,
            scrollY:        '30vh',
            scrollCollapse: true,
            scroller:       true,
            info:false
        } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.3/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.3/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>ZIP / Post code</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not simply set the `scroller` to `false`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge, thanks for the suggestion. I need scroller for performance. The data I receive could be thousands and that is the reason, I've enabled scroller.

Comment: probably `scrollY:        '30vh;min-height:100px',` meet your requirements.

Comment: It is because of CSS. Change max-height to 100% because your parent container ends up having less height than a child container and the parent has overflow set to auto, that adds a scroll bar to it. In this case, the height of parent container ends up being 59px and one of the child containers has the height of 70px.

Comment: Setting the scrolly value in pixel fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, as you say, empty rows will mess up the styling - they're not expected to be there. The best thing to do would be to filter out the empty rows before they get loaded into the table, by pre-processing the data returned. To do this, use the `xhr` event - this is explained with some good examples here: https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr